# Mysql how to fix specified key was too long error?

Tags: mysql, debugging, error-handling

Query:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_email_and_encrypted_password`  ON `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`)
```

Error:

```
14:28:47    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_email_and_encrypted_password`  ON `users` (`email`, `encrypted_password`)   Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes   0.00048 sec
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue. I checked various solutions but doesn't work.

Comment: which data type you have assigned  at the columns `email`, `encrypted_password` and which encodig you are using for these columns?

Comment: `email` and `encrypted_password ` both have varchar(255) type and charset  = `utf8mb4`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your encryption and columns length

an entry in your  index  could be

255 x 2 x 4  = 2040

... you should reduce the size  (255 char for a password seem too long and also for email)
eg:

password (48)
  email (128)

```
(128 + 48 ) * 4  =  704
```

If you can't recreate the table with the new columns length 
You can change the char length for the columns this way

The table must empty

```
 ALTER TABLE users  MODIFY email VARCHAR(128);
 ALTER TABLE users  MODIFY encrypted_password VARCHAR(48);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell which query to run. Sorry, I am new to mysql